# Change RAM single channel to dual channel

Tags: memory

I ran CPU-Z on my computer and found out that not only I have just one 4GB RAM in the motherboard, but also that my only RAM runs in a single channel. I read in a site that there is no single, dual, tri, or quad channel RAMs. Whats decides that, is the system with it is in. So, without a doubt...**Can't I change my RAM single channel to dual channel?** And also, **can I be sure that my motherboard have two slots for RAMs, or is it possible that mine only have one?**

Comment: You do not give us any useful information to help you out. Did you look inside the PC? What brand and model is it?

Comment: "Dual Channel" means that you have multiple sticks of RAM, and the CPU is able to read/write to multiple simultaneously.  Related reading : https://superuser.com/questions/852653/optimal-ram-configuration-one-large-dimm-vs-multiple-smaller-dimms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one RAM module you cannot make use of Dual Channel Memory.

> Dual-channel architecture requires a dual-channel-capable motherboard and **two or more** DDR, DDR2, DDR3, or DDR4 memory modules. The memory modules are installed into matching banks, which are usually color-coded on the motherboard. These separate channels allow the memory controller access to each memory module. It is not required that identical modules be used (if motherboard supports it), but this is often recommended for best dual-channel operation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture#Operation